# Find all characteristic curves of PDE $ u_{t}-(x^2-1)u_{xx}=0$ for $(x,t) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I am trying to solve the following problem from the 2021 Analysis of PDE Tripos exam:

Find all the characteristic curves to the equation
$$
u_{t}-(x^2-1)u_{xx}=0.
$$
When $x \neq 1,-1$, the definition given in lecture is that $\Sigma=\{\phi=0\}$ is the characteristic curve of the PDE if
$$
(x^2-1)\phi_{x}^{2}=0.
$$
we have that $\phi_{x}=0$. This $\phi(x,t)=f(t).$ Where $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is some function.

When $x=1,-1$ the characteristic curve satisfies
$$
\phi_{t}=0.
$$
This $\phi(1,t)=g(x)$ and $\phi(-1,t)=h(x)$ where $g,h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are functions.

I'm not sure how to piece the 3 characteristic curves together. Any help would be greatly apprecaited. Thank you.

Comment: How can $\phi(1, \color{red}{t}) = g(\color{blue}{x})$? Similarly for $h$.

Comment: You may have a problem insofar as characteristic curves are usually defined for first order (linear) systems, so the $\nabla^2 u$ term may be difficult,  Sure you don't mean $u_x$ instead of $u_{xx}$?